# Отделить socket от CPU_name

Tags: c#, winforms

есть CSV файл, в котором содержатся процессоры, выглядит так:

```
CPU_name,Socket
Xeon W-2133,LGA 2066
Xeon W-2135,LGA 2066
i7-4820K BOX,LGA 2011
i7-4820K OEM,LGA 2011
```

нужно отделить Socket от CPU_name, затем вывести их в ComboBox'ы разные. Также нужно, чтобы оно учитывало, что, к примеру, LGA 2066 (содержит такие-то CPU_name), LGA 2011 (содержит такие-то CPU_name), в нашем случае, при выборе в ComboBox1 LGA 2066 выпадает список в ComboBox2 из двух процессоров, при выборе LGA 2011 в ComboBox1 - также выпадает список из 2-ух процессоров в ComboBox2.

Мой код, который просто парсит, в начале код, который загружается при загрузки формы, для добавления в ComboBox спаршенных значений, далее код, который осуществляет парсинг, надеюсь поймете:

```cs
// Popitka sozdaniya lista s SocketsIntel;
            List<SOCKETintel> socksintel = SOCKETsIntel.GetSOCKETintelValues();
            foreach (SOCKETintel sock in socksintel)
            {
                comboBox12.Items.Add(sock);
            }


 public static class SOCKETsIntel
        {
            public static List<SOCKETintel> GetSOCKETintelValues()
            {
                string filePath = Path.Combine(GetPath + @"\INTEL_CPU\", "INTEL.csv"); // Sdelat' Proverky na nazvanie File;
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
                using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                {
                    var socksintel = new List<SOCKETintel>();
                    csv.Read();
                    csv.ReadHeader();
                    while (csv.Read())
                    {
                        var sock = new SOCKETintel
                        {
                            CPU_Name = csv.GetField<string>("CPU_name"),
                            Socket = csv.GetField<string>("Socket")
                        };
                        socksintel.Add(sock);
                    }
                    return socksintel;
                }
            }
        }

        // Sozdanie classa dlya parsinga Type/Brand/Model/Benchmark'a CPU;
        public class SOCKETintel
        {
            public string CPU_Name { get; set; }
            public string Socket { get; set; }
            public override string ToString() => $"{CPU_Name}";
        }
```

Что получаю Я: [image: Что получаю]

Что нужно мне: [image: Что нужно]

Comment: В `comboBox12.Items.Add(sock);` вы добавляете элемент класса `SOCKETintel`, когда как комбобокс ожидает текстовые данные, элемент через переопределенный вами `public override string ToString() => $"{CPU_Name}";` поступает в текстовом виде, и получается что получается.

Comment: И измените поле `Socket` на другое, использовать имена существующих классов - не лучшая идея.

Comment: Я могу и заменить ```{CPU_Name}``` на  ```{Socket}```, дело не в этом, дело в том, что мне нужно в ```ComboBox13.Items.Add(здесь Model(которая будет браться из {CPU_Name})```, который я пока не знаю как реализовать, а в ```ComboBox12.Items.Add(будет {Socket})```, вот как это реализовать? Я не знаю.

Comment: Например: `comboBox12.Items.Add(sock.Socket);` по аналогии и модель процессора заполняйте, тогда и не нужно переопределять `ToString()`.

Comment: Так-с, так легко? Спасибо. Заработало, далее, нужно решить еще один вопрос. Так как строки содержат такой вид: ```i7-4820K BOX,LGA 2011
i7-4820K OEM,LGA 2011```, то соответственно, ComboBox12, будет содержать все строки 2011, 2066 и так далее, столько же, сколько и ComboBox13 процессоров, это логично, но как теперь сделать так, чтобы при выборе 2011 - выводились только те строки CPU_Name, которые содержат этот параметр и в ComboBox12 были бы только, допустим 2011, 2066 я про это: https://imgur.com/XILPCV9

Comment: Вам нужно перед добавлением делать проверку на наличие `if (!comboBox12.Items.Contains(sock.Socket)) { comboBox12.Items.Add(sock.Socket); }`

Comment: По поводу выбора списка процессоров по сокету: одна проблема - один вопрос.

Comment: Хорошо, и на этом огромное спасибо. Литературу не подскажите? В C# примерно неделю, около того. В любом случае - огромнейшее спасибо, уже прорыв. ;3

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой пример.

Используется [привязка данных](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding). Свойство `DataSource`.
Что именно будет показываться, определяется свойством `DisplayMember`.
(Ознакомьтесь также со свойством `ValueMember`.)

Так как оба комбобокса прибиндены к одному источнику данных, то значения в них взаимозависимы. Возможно, вас устроит такое поведение.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinForms
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private ComboBox comboBoxCPU;
        private ComboBox comboBoxSocket;
        public Form1()
        {
            comboBoxSocket = new ComboBox { Parent = this };
            comboBoxCPU = new ComboBox { Parent = this, Left = 150 };

            var socksintel = new List<SOCKETintel>
            {
                new SOCKETintel{ CPU_Name = "Xeon W-2133", Socket = "LGA 2066" },
                new SOCKETintel{ CPU_Name = "Xeon W-2135", Socket = "LGA 2066" },
                new SOCKETintel{ CPU_Name = "i7-4820K BOX", Socket = "LGA 2011" },
                new SOCKETintel{ CPU_Name = "i7-4820K OEM", Socket = "LGA 2011" }
            };
            comboBoxSocket.DisplayMember = nameof(SOCKETintel.Socket);
            comboBoxSocket.DataSource = socksintel;

            comboBoxCPU.DisplayMember = nameof(SOCKETintel.CPU_Name);
            comboBoxCPU.DataSource = socksintel;
        }
    }
    public class SOCKETintel
    {
        public string CPU_Name { get; set; }
        public string Socket { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

Можно добиться желаемого поведения кода следующим образом.
Добавим дополнительный класс:

```
public class Cpu
{
    public string Socket { get; set; }
    public List<string> Names { get; set; }
}
```

И используем `BindingSource`.

```
var cpus = socksintel
    .GroupBy(s => s.Socket, s => s.CPU_Name)
    .Select(g => new Cpu { Socket = g.Key, Names = g.ToList() })
    .ToList();

var bindingSourceSocket = new BindingSource();
bindingSourceSocket.DataSource = cpus;

comboBoxSocket.DisplayMember = nameof(Cpu.Socket);
comboBoxSocket.DataSource = bindingSourceSocket;

var bindingSourceNames = new BindingSource(bindingSourceSocket, nameof(Cpu.Names));

comboBoxCPU.DataSource = bindingSourceNames;
```

Трюк здесь в том, что используются два `BindingSource`. Первый ссылается на коллецию с данными. А второй ссылается на первый, указывая вложенный список.

---

Ну, если вам привязка данных совсем непонятна, то вот код без неё, с ручным заполнением свойства `Items` комбобоксов.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinForms
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private ComboBox comboBoxCPU;
        private ComboBox comboBoxSocket;
        private Dictionary<string, object[]> dictionary;

        public Form1()
        {
            comboBoxSocket = new ComboBox { Parent = this };
            comboBoxCPU = new ComboBox { Parent = this, Left = 150 };

            var socksintel = new List<SOCKETintel>
                {
                    new SOCKETintel {CPU_Name = "Xeon W-2133", Socket = "LGA 2066"},
                    new SOCKETintel {CPU_Name = "Xeon W-2135", Socket = "LGA 2066"},
                    new SOCKETintel {CPU_Name = "i7-4820K BOX", Socket = "LGA 2011"},
                    new SOCKETintel {CPU_Name = "i7-4820K OEM", Socket = "LGA 2011"}
                };

            dictionary = socksintel
                .GroupBy(s => s.Socket, s => (object)s.CPU_Name)
                .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToArray());

            foreach (var pair in dictionary)
            {
                comboBoxSocket.Items.Add(pair.Key);
            }
            comboBoxSocket.SelectedValueChanged +=
                ComboBoxSocket_SelectedValueChanged;
        }

        private void ComboBoxSocket_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var socket = (string)comboBoxSocket.SelectedItem;

            comboBoxCPU.Items.Clear();
            comboBoxCPU.Items.AddRange(dictionary[socket]);

            comboBoxCPU.Text = null;
            //comboBoxCPU.Text = (string)comboBoxCPU.Items[0];
        }
    }
    public class SOCKETintel
    {
        public string CPU_Name { get; set; }
        public string Socket { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Для наших целей проще всего использовать словарь. Ключом в нём будет название сокета, а значением - массив названий процессоров.
Массив сделан типа `object` - это позволяет использовать `AddRange`.

Как создаётся словарь. Сперва данные группируются по названию сокета, затем помещаются в `Dictionary`.
Если код LINQ непонятен, то срочно его учить! Ныне это основа основ.

В обработчике события очищаем коллекцию `Items` от предыдущих значений и добавляем новые из словаря.
В завершение нужно очистить свойство `Text`. Потому что в нём будет предыдущее значение. Как вариант, можно задать ему одно из значений текущей коллекции.

Comment: а как-то так нельзя сделать, намного проще? ```If comboBox12.SelectedItem = "LGA 2066" 
{
 comboBox13.Items.Add(Тогда добавляем в Модель строчки, которые содеражать в {CPU_Name} - {LGA 2066}
}```

Comment: @0day. - Если вы считаете, что так проще, то делайте. Но дело в том, что работать напрямую с GUI-контролами не рекомендуется. Во всех современных графических фреймворках используется привязка данных. Вся работа ведётся с типизированными источниками данных.

Comment: Ух, какие сложные слова, если не сложно дайте литературу где об этом почитать, а касаемо, легче, не легче, я не знаю, я просто предположил, а как реализовать - не знаю...

Comment: Просто я хочу код свой потом понимать, чтобы в дальнейшем его усовершенствовать, а то, что я вижу выше - я не совсем понимаю (( Относительно не давно в C#, сразу за программу взялся, которая пришла в голову, по ходу пытаюсь изучать язык.

Comment: @0day.- см. апдейт

Comment: если уж делать так, то выдает ошибку, во-первых: ```dictionary``` не существует в текущем контексте, делаю замену на: ```SOCKETsIntel.GetSOCKETintelValues()```, тогда выдает ошибку: ```Ошибка CS1503 Аргумент 1: не удается преобразовать из "object" в "int".```, ссылаясь на ```[socket]```

Comment: @0day. - я опубликовал полностью рабочий пример. Достаточно скопировать его и запустить. / `dictionary` - _поле_ формы. / Понятия не имею, что такое `SOCKETsIntel.GetSOCKETintelValues()` - в моём коде нет таких классов и методов.